# How to color the background only for two out of 6 boxplots in a single plot?

Tags: r, boxplot

I have 6 datasets for which I need to plot boxplot using R in a single plot. Out of  6 , 2 are of more importance so I want to highlight them by shading their background . Is it possible to selectively shade background behind the boxplot for few leaving others as it is using boxplot() function of R ?
[image: Just like this image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use function `rect()` and give coordinates of lower left and upper right corner and color. Argument `lty=0` ensures that there are no borders. Function `boxplot()` is used twice because `rect()` will hide first boxplots. `add=TRUE` in second `boxplot()` ensures that plot is made on the same graphic.

```
a<-rep(c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g5","g6"),each=10)
b<-rnorm(60)    
boxplot(b~a)
rect(0.5,-3,1.5,3,col="grey75",lty=0)
rect(2.5,-3,3.5,3,col="grey75",lty=0)
boxplot(b~a,add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I am asking . Please have a look once at the question I have edited just now.